# Filter not working when I create custom view (screenshots attached)

Tags: list, workflow, 2013, filter, view

I have a list named "Test".

On this list I enabled approval workflow named "Test".

If you take a look at screenshot below which shows "All Items" view you will see 3 items, 2 approved and 1 rejected.

[image]

I created a new view named "Test" to show only those items which were approved using this workflow. But when I apply filter as shown in screenshot below, this custom view doesn't display any records.

[image]

How do I apply filter so only those items are showed which were approved in workflow?

Comment: Frank, are you sure you are looking at the correct view? Did you applied the filter on All Items view, or you created a new view? By default All Items view is selected, so if you created a new view, you should choose the view shown in horizontal list beside Find an item box!

Comment: Yes I made a copy of All Items, named it Test and then applied filter on it.

Comment: So you sure you are looking at "Test" view rather than "All Items" view!

Comment: Yes I am looking at "Test" view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter it based on workflow status
This list might be useful when you creates a view based on workflow status.
 If you are creating a view for a list filtered by the workflow status, you would need use the number rather than the words (e.g. 2 instead of In Progress, 4 instead of Cancelled etc)

Status        Value

Not Started 0

Failed on Start 1

In Progress 2

Error Occurred  3

Canceled    4

Completed   5

Failed on Start (retrying)  6

Error Occurred (retrying)   7

Canceled    15

Approved    16

Rejected    17

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and never found an answer, but in continuing to just "try stuff out," I stumbled across a solution.

Go to "Edit View" and scroll down to the "Folders" link (or if you're creating the view for the first time, be sure to scroll down after setting your parameters)

Click the plus sign next to Folders

Click the radio button next to "Show all items without folders"

When I did that, the correct documents showed up in the custom view.  Hope that helps!